# Getting error message when trying to call a method using async/await when using a .net mixpanel project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I am using this mixpanel .net project:

https://cndrsn.wordpress.com/2014/04/

On the page there is an example of calling the MixpanelClient.GetCurrentClient() using await but I get this error when doing so:

Cannot await 'Mixpanel.MixpanelClient'

Here is my method:

```
    public async Task<string> TrackMixPanelLoggedIn(int userId)
    {
        string token = "mytoken!";
        MixpanelClient _client = await MixpanelClient.GetCurrentClient();
        TrackingEvent evt = new TrackingEvent("User logged in");
        evt.Properties = new TrackingEventProperties(token);
        evt.Properties.DistinctId = userId.ToString();
        _client.Track(evt);
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume that `MixpanelClient.GetCurrentClient()` is not an asynchronous method?

Comment: What does `MixpanelClient.GetCurrentClient()` return? `async\await` are not magical keywords that make all things asynchronous.

Comment: But the author of the MixPanelClient is using it in his example:

MixpanelClient
The main class is MixpanelClient, it’s that little fellow that allows you to track events and profile updates. Furthermore, if ever sending an element failed, the client will automatically save it locally to automatically send them as a batch later on.

Here’s how to retrieve an instance of it:

_client = await MixpanelClient.GetCurrentClient();
This method is awaitable as on the first call, the client checks if there’s any unsent element and sends them if so.

Example from: https://cndrsn.wordpress.com/2014/04/

Comment: Then he's either wrong or is using a different version (newer?) of the library.

Comment: The error message tells you that the function is not awaitable, it's as simple as that.

Comment: That is strange - I just checked - I do have the latest 1.2.4 nuget package Installed

Comment: I'm looking at the library now, there is nothing awaitable about that function (or any other functions for that matter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the author of the package has incorrect documentation (or perhaps has not released the correct code?)

The metadata for `MixpanelClient` looks like this, as you can see, there is nothing in here that can be `await`ed.

```
public sealed class MixpanelClient
{
    public string UserAgent { get; set; }
    public static DateTime ConvertToDateTime(long unixDateTicks);
    public static string ConvertToMixpanelDate(DateTime dateTime);
    public void CreateAlias(string token, string originalId, string newId);
    public static MixpanelClient GetCurrentClient();
    public void SaveElement(MixpanelEntity element);
    public static long ToEpochTime(DateTime date);
    public void Track(MixpanelEntity element);
    public void TrySendLocalElements();
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks for clearing this up. Is there any way that I can call these methods without blocking the main thread in my asp.net application.

Comment: That's a different question, but it's been solved many times elsewhere.